# Running shell script in background via java exec() returns exit code 127

Tags: java, ssh, exec

I'm trying to run a command on a linux box via java Runtime.exec() that will ssh to another machine and kick off a script in the background, redirecting output to /dev/null.  The script has the potential to run forever, hence why I send it to the background.

```
String command = "ssh " + machineToRunOn + " 'simple.sh &>/dev/null &'";
 try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            int exitStatus = p.exitValue();
 }
```

The problem is the exitStatus is always non-zero (127 specifically) and the script does not get run.

I can run the same command by hand in a terminal and it works fine.  Likewise, I can run a script that I don't send to the background or re-direct via exec() and it runs fine as well.

I realize using exec() is not the best solution but I can't figure out why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the single quotes was the answer.  Still trying to get to the bottom of why.

```
String command = "ssh " + machineToRunOn + " simple.sh &>/dev/null &";
 try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            int exitStatus = p.exitValue();
 }
```